# ros_control packages missing from Jade

Tags: gazebo, ros-control, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just updated to Jade, and I'm having trouble running a Gazebo simulation using my previously working packages.

Right now I'm focused on this error:

```
File "/home/sam/aav-ros-car/aav_car_ws/src/aav_description/nodes/ackermann_controller.py", line 125, in 
    from controller_manager_msgs.srv import ListControllers
ImportError: No module named controller_manager_msgs.srv
```

I am seeing this too, though I think it's unrelated:

```
/opt/ros/jade/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient: 17: .: Can't open /usr/share/gazebo//setup.sh
/opt/ros/jade/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver: 22: .: Can't open /usr/share/gazebo//setup.sh
```

It looks like I am missing the service message definitions for `ros_control`, and that according to [the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control#Install), this ought to be solved by `sudo apt-get install ros-jade-ros-control ros-jade-ros-controllers`.  But that doesn't work either:

```
/opt/ros/jade$ sudo apt-get install ros-jade-ros-control ros-jade-ros-controllers
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-ros-control
E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-ros-controllers
```

This is on a standard 64-bit Intel system running Ubuntu 14.04.  Here's the contents of my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`:

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty main
```

My system seems to otherwise be working fine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221715/ros_control-packages-missing-from-jade/) by [Sam Bishop](https://answers.ros.org/users/21272/sam-bishop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2015-11-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know why, but according to [debbuild/jade.html?q=controller_manager_msgs](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/jade.html?q=controller_manager_msgs), `controller_manager_msgs` (and almost [all other ros_control](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/jade.html?q=ros_control) packages) are not yet available in the *public* ROS package repositories. They should be installable from the [shadow repository](http://wiki.ros.org/ShadowRepository) though.

That would explain why you can't `apt-get install ros-jade-ros-control`. Were you able to install any of the other `ros_control`packages on Jade?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sam Bishop](https://answers.ros.org/users/21272/sam-bishop/) on 2015-11-30**:
Thank you so much! No, I hadnt' tried. It looks like the `ros_control` packages [haven't been released for Jade yet](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/issues/201). It hadn't occurred to me that a ROS release might not include such a critical set of packages. I assumed the fault was mine.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-30**:
The packages have been released, they just haven't reached the repositories most people use to install ROS from. If you setup your system to use the *shadow-fixed* repository (see the wiki page I linked), you can already install them on your Jade system. Otherwise, wait for the next sync.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-30**:
Also: you can always build packages from source. I assume that is what most users have been doing with `ros_control`.